# PowerBI - Comparing two similar sets of data (Many to Many)

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to compare to sets of data that are very similar. I have done a bridge relation and used M:M relationship on PowerBI but I am still not getting the result I want.

Here is an example of the data:
Dataset 1

```
Name | Service | Usage 
 A   |    1    |  10
 A   |    2    |  20
 B   |    1    |  10
 B   |    2    |  10
 C   |    1    |  20
 C   |    2    |  10
```

Dataset 2

```
Name | Service | Usage 
 A   |    1    |  40
 A   |    2    |  20
 B   |    1    |  40
 B   |    2    |  10
 C   |    1    |  40
 C   |    2    |  10
```

Desired output

```
Name | Service | Usage 1 | Usage 2  
 A   |    1    |   10    |  40
 A   |    2    |   20    |  20
 B   |    1    |   10    |  40
 B   |    2    |   10    |  10
 C   |    1    |   20    |  40 
 C   |    2    |   10    |  10
```

Is this possible in PowerBI?

Comment: Instead of a bridge, create 2 dimensions: one with names. and one with services, and connect them to both tables (as 1:M relations). Then you will be able to drill across easily.

Answer (score 0):

One approach (as suggested in comments), is to separate the distinct `Name` and `Service` values into separate dimension tables, in the query editor:

Names:

```
= Table.FromList(List.Distinct(List.Combine({#"Dataset 1"[Name], #"Dataset 2"[Name]})),Splitter.SplitByNothing(),{"Name"})
```

Services:

```
= Table.FromList(List.Distinct(List.Combine({#"Dataset 1"[Service], #"Dataset 2"[Service]})),Splitter.SplitByNothing(),{"Service"})
```

Create the DAX measures you want:

`Usage 1 = SUM ( 'Dataset 1'[Usage] )`

`Usage 2 = SUM ( 'Dataset 2'[Usage] )`

Now create relationships between the fact tables (Dataset 1, Dataset 2) and the dimension tables (Names, Services):

[image]

Then simply layout the visual as required:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another approach may be to combine your dataset fact tables into one table, with an added "dataset" column:

Create your "combined" table in the query editor.

Combined Table:

```
= Table.Combine({Table.AddColumn(#"Dataset 1", "Dataset", each "Dataset 1", type text), Table.AddColumn(#"Dataset 2", "Dataset", each "Dataset 2", type text)})
```

Now use this table as your single source - either with a crosstab visual:

[image]

Or by adding separate measure for each dataset:

`Usage 1 = CALCULATE ( SUM('Combined Data'[Usage]), 'Combined Data'[Dataset] = "Dataset 1" )`

`Usage 2 = CALCULATE ( SUM('Combined Data'[Usage]), 'Combined Data'[Dataset] = "Dataset 2" )`

[image]